# AJAX post data is null when it reaches the ASP.NET Core 2.1 controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-core

I'm posting data to an ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1.2 page using this jQuery code:

```
function OnCountryChange() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/OnCountryChange",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        headers: {
            "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name = __RequestVerificationToken]').val()
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            sCountryCode: "Test 123"
        })
    });
}
```

I am receiving the post in the controller with this method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("/OnCountryChange")]
public IActionResult OnCountryChange([FromBody] string sCountryCode)
{
    logger.LogDebug($"Country code is: {sCountryCode ?? "null"}");

    return Json(sCountryCode);
}
```

The output printed to the log is:

> Country code is: null

The raw request body (viewed using Fiddler) looks like this:

```
{"sCountryCode":"Test 123"}
```

Why isn't the data being passed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not familiar with `C#`,but in your question you have add

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

in your `Ajax` method which means the data parameter is `json` format,so you need to access as `json` object instead of access string directly.

Two ways to solve it:

a. Change your `C#` controller method to access like a `json` object

b. Send `Ajax` parameter without `json`,code similar to below:

```
function OnCountryChange() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/OnCountryChange",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        headers: {
            "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name = __RequestVerificationToken]').val()
        },
        data: {sCountryCode: "Test 123"}
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing the string in the controller method to JObject worked.

Comment: @Coder6841 Glad to help you!

Comment: @Coder6841 I have the exact same issue in my solution. I have the exact same country dropdown AJAX call, to get states based on country.  Can you share your final working code?

Comment: @exInt The AJAX works, just the C# method needs to be changed like this: `public JObject OnCountryChange([FromBody] JObject joRequest)`