# ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC send data from JavaScript to Action method using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest

This is similar to below but without Ajax. I am using JavaScript and XMLHttpRequest

[AJAX post data is null when it reaches the ASP.NET Core 2.1 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336590/ajax-post-data-is-null-when-it-reaches-the-asp-net-core-2-1-controller)

**Everything works good in ASP.NET MVC but I am learning ASP.NET Core MVC.**

**A button in Home.cshtml calls below JavaScript method which intern calls a method named Test in HomeController.cs.**

**My problem is if I keep break point in my Test method serverName and port are both null**

```
function MyMethod() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/Home/Test";
    var input = {};
    input.serverName = document.getElementById("serverName").value;
    input.port = document.getElementById("port").value;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var jsResp = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if (jsResp.Status == "Success") {
                //show success
            }
            else {
                //show error
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(input));
}



[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Test(string serverName, string port)
 {
   try
     {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverName) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(port))
         {
            return Json(new { Status = "Error", Message = "Missing Data" });
         }
        else 
         {
        return Json(new { Status = "Success", Message = "Got data" });
         }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
        {
             return Json(new { Status = "Error", Message = e.Message });
        }
 }
```

I even tried below but none helps

```
public JsonResult Test(JObject serverName, JObject port) -- controller method not hiting

public JsonResult Test(object serverName, object port) -- not allowing me to cast into string

public JsonResult Test([FromBody] string serverName, [FromBody] string port)
```

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare good request with bad request.  Usually these type error are due to the default headers value being different in the first request.

Comment: My problem is if I keep break point in my Test method serverName and port are both null

Comment: You sent one string (stringified object), but are telling your controller to expect two values.

Comment: Do use a break point when capturing sniffer data.  Just let it run so you can compare good and bad request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your content type is `application/json;charset=UTF-8`, you need to use `[FromBody]` and receive the data as an object based on your situation.

Besides, you could only use `[FromBody]` in the action parameters once(from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#frombody-attribute))

> Don't apply [FromBody] to more than one parameter per action method. The ASP.NET Core runtime delegates the responsibility of reading the request stream to the input formatter. Once the request stream is read, it's no longer available to be read again for binding other [FromBody] parameters.

You could follow below steps to pass data correctly:

1.Create a ViewModel:

```
public class ServerModel
{
    public string serverName { get; set; }
    public string port { get; set; }
}
```

2.Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Test([FromBody] ServerModel data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.serverName) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.port))
            {
                return Json(new { Status = "Error", Message = "Missing Data" });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Status = "Success", Message = "Got data" });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { Status = "Error", Message = e.Message });
        }
    }
```