# Passed data to asp.net core controller using ajax is null

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to call a asp.net core controller using ajax but the passed value is null.

I debug the javacript in order to check if the parameters in ajax is correct.
The OrderType is **IR ID** and the  OrderKeyword is **test**

please see the screenshot

[image]

And this is the model

```
public class OrderSearchInfo
    {
        public int OrderType { get; set; }
        public string OrderKeyword { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SearchOrder([FromBody]OrderSearchInfo order)
        {
            
            return View();
        }
```

while debugging and checking the value of the **OrderSearchInfo order** is **null**

[image]

What did i do wrong? And how can i solve this? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AJAX post data is null when it reaches the ASP.NET Core 2.1 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336590/ajax-post-data-is-null-when-it-reaches-the-asp-net-core-2-1-controller)

Comment: Does the request have `Content-Type: application/json` header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there are some main points to check:

- data types: in your model, there is `int OrderType`, but in JS you have `OrderType: "IR_ID"` which isn't a number and could not be mapped to `int`
- if your form has `RequestVerificationToken`, you should pass it in the request's headers
- routing (ensure request URL matches ASP.NET expected one

P.S. please add your suggestions for further checks in comments, to make this answer more applicable for many people.

Comment: changing the datatype to string solved the problem.  i didn't noticed it even checking for the code for hours now. thank you